# Jekyll not displaying images from Github repository

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I just created a Jekyll blog using the `minima` theme and wanted to embed some images.

If I do the following I can embed an image from a Github page:

`![Logo Jekyll](http://memofil.github.io/assets/images/categories/jekyll-logo.png)`

However, if I try to embed an image from a Github repository I end up with a broken link and no image is shown:

`![Screenshot](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/screenshot.png)`

Why is that the case?

I used the command `sudo bundle exec jekyll serve` to test the site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can only add an image from a Github repository if you use the `raw` link.

Doing this

```
![Screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/minima/master/screenshot.png)
```

instead of this

```
![Screenshot](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/screenshot.png)
```

solved my problem.

Comment: You can also use the relative path filter if the image is stored in your assets/ folder.